# Web Browser Control with vertical bar and navigation to bottom method!

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i am adding html to silverlight's web browser control .what i want is ,

web browser control always navigated to the bottom and

web browser control to show horizontal and vertical bar.

thanks

jamal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is in this thread.

[check this](http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/196186.aspx)