# Silverlight WebBrowser Control Query!

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

i am adding html to silverlight's web browser control .what i want is ,

web browser control always navigated to the bottom and

web browser control to show horizontal and vertical bar.

thanks

jamal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Web Browser Control with vertical bar and navigation to bottom method!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475751/web-browser-control-with-vertical-bar-and-navigation-to-bottom-method)

Comment: yes it is , actaully i thaught it was not posted earlier